# Is there a quota for "gcloud auth print-access-token"?

Tags: authentication, gcloud

We use the following:

```
curl -H "X-Access-Token: $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
```

in a lot of manual testing scenarios.

Is there a rate limiting on the token generation? For instance:

- 20/second # example
- 10000/day # example

Comment: Which method of Authenticating are you using? "gcloud auth login" or the Service account key?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer but:

- there are *always* quotas; I suspect for auth, these limits will surpass volumes that any reasonable customer can originate.
- access tokens usually live for an hour (3600s) and you could cache these and reuse them to reduce the volume of requests. You can introspect the token's expiry through:

```sh
# Acquire Access Token and optimistically start timer at 3600s
TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
EXPIRY=3600
while [ ${EXPIRY} -gt 0 ]
do
  # Update Expiry without reacquiring Access Token 
  EXPIRY=$(\
    curl \
    --silent https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?access_token=${TOKEN} \
    | jq -r .expires_in\
  )
  # Do stuff
  echo ${EXPIRY}
  sleep 60s
done
```

- I had an issue once where a customer was running a large volume of user tests and falling foul of automated abuse detection. I think it would be prudent to review whether mocks and caching can be employed in the tests; e2e testing to provide proxies of your users' experience is reasonable but when these fail, it's difficult to isolate what's going wrong.
- I've noticed an uptick in the use of `gcloud auth print-[access|identity]-token` and have a suspicion that these commands are being employed for reasons other than for what they were originally intended. In most cases, non-gcloud apps would be better making auth calls directly rather than delegating this to exec'ing through gcloud

Answer (score -1):

I found this information, you can refresh up to 50 token for user accounts but there isn't a limit for service account according with this document [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration)

I hope this information be useful for you.

Comment: These are the number of different refresh tokens that a user account can create, but there is only one refresh token per machine where you have authenticated that is generated and saved when you run `gcloud auth login`. Re-running `gcloud auth print-access-token` will use the saved refresh token to get a short-lived access token, but in the docs you shared there is no limit specified to the access tokens created, not the rate in which you can call the `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` endpoint (the one used by `gcloud auth print-access-token`).